# Changing switch to gigabit, decreased network performance for popcorn hour device

Tags: network-protocols

Recently I upgraded a local switch in a friends network from 100 MBit (TPLink) to gigabit (cisco sg300 series).

To my surprise, his performance for transferring files (FTP: filezilla client) to a popcorn hour A210 device, suddenly decreased drastically. Where he used to get +- 9 MB/s , he now transfers at 2 MB/s.

This is of course a surprise to me. I never ran into a situation where replacing a 100 MBit with a Gigabit device slowed things down. I'm wondering if anyone has any idea on why this may happen (theoretical approach) and some actual suggestions on how we can debug this sort of thing. (practical approach).

For the record: the gigabit switch is not defect. Transfers to other devices are very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the A210 device has auto negotation on enabled on link speed/duplex?

If one side has autonegotiation and the other is set to any static value, the device with autonegotiation will fallback to 100/half duplex and you will get a lot of crc errors.

If possible make sure that both the switch and the end device is set to auto. If that is not an option make sure that both the port on the switch and the end device is configured with the exact same settings for speed and duplex.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that it was the auto negotiation that does not work properly with the A210 device. When i told the cisco switch to report that port as 100Mbit (only announce was enough), it seems to do the trick.